# Recorrer array varias veces con php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un campo de **tallas** en una tabla de **productos**, el campo tiene varios indices separados por coma que son las llaves primarias de registros de la tabla de **tallas** que estos a su vez tienen la descripcion detallada de cada talla.

Al momento de yo insertar una nueva talla en el producto, antes necesito verificar si ese producto ya tiene una talla con el numero que se va a insertar, entonces necesito recorrer cada uno de los indices del campo de tallas en la tabla de productos y verificar si existe o no una talla con ese numero, y si es asi entonces mandar una respuesta con json diciendo que ya existe una talla con ese numero, y si no ejecutar el insert, acá muestro lo que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código me funciona pero solo con el último registro, osea con la talla 41, con la 37 no me está funcionando ¿me podrían ayudar?

```
$producto = $_POST["producto"];
    $tallas = $_POST["tallas"];
    $array = explode(",", $tallas);
    
    $data["numero"] = $_POST["numero"];
    $data["cantidad"] = $_POST["cantidad"];
    foreach($array as $ar) {
        $db->where("id", $ar);
        $db->where("numero", $_POST["numero"]);
        $resultado_numero .= $db->getOne("tallas", "numero");
    }
    
    if(!empty($resultado_numero)) {
        $respuesta = 1;
        $resultadojs["elementos"] = $respuesta;
    } else {
        $talla = $db->insert("tallas", $data);
        if($talla) {
            $datos["tallas"] = $tallas.','.$talla;
            $db->where("id", $producto);
            $act_producto = $db->update("productos", $datos);
            if($act_producto) {
                $tallasmod = $tallas.','.$talla;
                $array = explode(",", $tallasmod);
                for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
                    $db->where("id", $array[$i]);
                    $db->orderBy("numero", "DESC");
                    $resultado_tallas = $db->get("tallas");
                    if($resultado_tallas) {
                        foreach($resultado_tallas as $r) {
                            if($r["cantidad"] == 1) {
                                $vc = '<font color="red">'.$r["cantidad"].' Par</font>';
                            } else {
                                $vc = $r["cantidad"].' Pares';
                            }

                            $datost .= '<div><small><b>Talla: '.$r["numero"].'</b> - '.$vc.'</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="editarTalla(this)" data-id="'.$r["id"].'" style="color: #735c54;"><span uk-icon="icon: pencil; ratio: 0.8;"></span></a>&nbsp;<a onclick="eliminarTalla(this)" data-id="'.$r["id"].'" style="color: #735c54;"><span uk-icon="icon: trash; ratio: 0.8;"></span></a></div>' ;
                        }

                        $db->where("id", $producto);
                        $resultado_producto_tallas = $db->getOne("productos", "tallas");
                    } else {
                        echo 'No se realizo la segunda consulta';
                    }
                }
                $resultadojs["elementos"] = $datost;
                $resultadojs["tallas"] = $resultado_producto_tallas["tallas"];
            } else {
                echo 'No se actualizo el producto';
            }
        } else { 
            echo 'No se agrego la Talla';
        }
    }
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    print json_encode($resultadojs);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta para colocar el código como texto porque es difícil interpretarlo en imagen.

Comment: Sí, disculpa, ya lo he actualizado

Comment: Me parece que: 1) No deberías concatenar valores en `$resultado_numero`, quedando `$resultado_numero = $db->getOne("tallas", "numero");` 2) El bloque `if(!empty($resultado_numero))` y todo su contenido deben estar dentro del ciclo para que aplique los cambios a cada talla.

Comment: Ya lo organicé, pero si meto la talla 37, entonces no lo hace, pero como también está la talla 40 si la inserta, osea solo lo hace con el último registro

Comment: ¿Por qué incluyes el número como criterio: `$db->where("numero", $_POST["numero"]);`? Y, ¿de dónde salen las tallas separadas por coma? Puede que tengas un serio problema de diseño en ese punto.

Comment: Ya he arreglado el problema, lo hice guardando el resultado en un array y luego validando:

Si lo que viene en el array es NULL, significa que no hay ninguna talla con ese número y puedo hacer el insert, y si no entonces que devuelva la alerta